# Prove that $(P_{ij})^{-1}=P_{ij}$ in matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Definitions :
1. $I_n$ is a matrix which has $n$ rows and $n$ columns. For each element like $I_{ij}$, the element's value is equal to $1$ if $i=j$. Otherwise, It's $0$.
2. $P_{ij}$ is the matrix created from substitution of the rows $i$ and $j$ of $I_n$.
Note 1 : $P_{ij}$ is called  an elementary matrix.

Prove this theorem :
$P_{ij}=(P_{ij})^{-1}$

Note 2 :  My problem is not just about this theorem. Every time i want to prove something about matrices, I face the problem that the number of rows and the number of columns are not fixed. So, I can prove a theorem for a matrix which has $4$ rows and $4$ columns, for example. But, I can't prove the same theorem without fixing the number of rows and columns.

Note 3 : When trying to prove this theorem, I found that i have another problem too ! $i$ and $j$ are not fixed. I don't know how to use divide and conquer.

Note 4 : It would be best if you show me how to use induction to prove this theorem. Because that way, I can prove many other theorems too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enough to show that $P_{ij}^2=I_n$. That means for any vector $x$, we have to show $P^2_{ij}x=x$, that is, $P_{ij}(P_{ij}x)=x$.

For a vector $x$, $P_{ij}x$ is a vector obtained by interchanging the $i$th and $j$th entries of $x$. Applying $P_{ij}$ again gives you another interchanging, and hence you get back $x$. Thus proved!

Comment: :D Thanks to you, the question is completely destroyed :)) perfect !

Comment: You were unnecessarily complicating things. Linear algebraic arguments are often very straightforward if you stop to think about it.